# 'Where's the guy that told I am an idiot' vs "Where's the guy who told I am an idiot" usage.

Tags: sentence-construction

I was said that the 'Where's the guy that told I am an idiot' is correct.

Comment: Best to use *said* there: "Where's the guy who **said** I'm an idiot?" Otherwise, use *you*: "Where's the guy who **told you** I'm an idiot?" Doesn't have to be *you*, but you need an object after *told*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relative pronouns ('who', 'that', and 'which') introduce relative clauses which provide further information about the preceding object, the antecedent.

Always prefer 'who' when referring to a person, group of persons, or vessel. Some other things, e.g. pets, can be considered sufficiently person-like to justify the use of 'who'.

Then, prefer 'that' for situations where the following information is helping to define the antecedent, e.g. describe the subset to which it belongs.

Otherwise, prefer 'which'.

There is not universal agreement over these priorities. People tend to use 'that' more often than grammarians would consider correct.

Answer (score 1):

Neither are grammatically correct.

If the guy told you personally that you are an idiot you would say:

> Where's the guy who **told me** I am an idiot?

If the guy said it to someone else, not to you, you would say:

> Where's the guy who **said** I am an idiot?

Comment: Neither *is* grammatically correct.